# asyncio: 50ms delay between put_nowait and get to/from a queue

Tags: queue, python-3.6, python-asyncio, event-loop

I have a python asyncio application, with several coroutines being run within a single thread. Some data is being passed using queues.

The queue consumer looks like this:

```py
    async def queue_consumer(q):
        """Consume from an asyncio.Queue, making it an async iterable"""
        while True:
            try:
                e = await q.get()
                yield e
            except:
                continue
```

the consumer is being pulled from with `async for`.
<strike>In this particular case the coroutine which consumes from a specific queue sequentially calls some code which puts data into its queue with `put_nowait`.</strike>
EDIT: In this particular case coroutine A, which is listening for inbound network traffic, puts message into queue of coroutine B.

I have noticed that there is a consistent **~50ms delay** between a call to `put_nowait` in coroutine A and then the data being processed as a result of pulling it from queue async iterable in coroutine B.

I suspect it might have something to do with some asyncio internal polling resolution, but I am not sure, not I would suspect where such configuration could be modified.

I would be very much interested in increasing event polling frequency in the asyncio `loop`, hence, decreasing observed delay between `put_nowait` and `get` to/from a queue between coroutines. Maybe also there's a way to hint asyncio framework to process items from the queue earlier?

NB: the application I am working with is not doing any computationally demanding work.

Comment: What happens between the `put_nowait` and the next `await` that actually yields back to the event loop?

Comment: @dirn I have corrected the problem specification. Is your question still valid?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a minimal example that we can run? E.g. just start two coroutines, print `time.time()` at the appropriate points, etc.

Comment: Yes, my question is still valid. Unless the next line of code after `put_nowait` is something that yields control back to the loop (eg, `await asyncio.sleep(0)`), the coroutine that pulls from the queue may not even get a chance to check it for most of those 50ms.

Comment: @dirn It turns out the problem was quite simple, and rather embarassing. I have learnt more about asyncio thanks to that, though. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by my app doing some UI updates with `prompt_toolkit`. I tracked this down by placing some measurements within `_run_once`. Anyway, the queue was not being processed because the event loop was busy executing some UI code that I did not expect to take so much time.